# Django request.META 2

Tags: django, request, metadata

I understand everything from this code:

```
def display_meta(request):
    values = request.META.items()
    values.sort()
    html = []
    for k, v in values:
        html.append('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>' % (k, v))
    return HttpResponse('<table>%s</table>' % '\n'.join(html))
```

Except this line:  '\n'.join(html)

So \n creates a new line for every table I assume. 
But what does join(html) do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically puts a newline between every item in `html`.

So if

```
html = ['<!DOCTYPE html>', '<html>', '<body>', '<p>']
```

that piece of code will create this string:

```
"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>
"""
```

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Comment: Nice thanks! 

So its dicitem1 + \n +dictitem2 +\n ...etc. 

And I can decide which String I want to put inbeetween? 

If I write: '/'.join(html) it would be?:

<!DOCTYPE html>/<html>/<body>/<p>

With your example?

Comment: @MacPython Yes, it would concatenate strings with `/`.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it and it still gave me a table with key : value pairs. The only difference was that at the top line he added /////////////////////////////////////////
Which is wired. But interesting. I thought it would be one line seperated by /. 
Well dont want to waste your time. Thanks again!

Comment: In your case join only concatenates table rows and you can't put content other then special characters such as `\n` (newline) between table rows.